# C++ LibCurl use defined range of ports for requests

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have been scraping a website (successfully using curl.h) with an application that also connects to a couple of TCPIP sockets to consume some data (successfully too). This app runs for hours gathering data from these two sources, the problem I am having is that after some time running successfully I get disconnected from the TCPIP socket because curl connects using the same IP and port that the TCPIP socket uses. So to solve this issue I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to set up manually either the IP or the port that curl uses. Here is sample of the ways I have been trying to accomplish it.

```
void BaseScraper::ScrapWebsite()
{
    std::string URL = "https://some_website.com";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &BaseScraper::CurlWriter);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &curlBuffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());

        //These are the ways I have been trying to manipulate local IP/port unsuccessfully :(
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4, "192.168.1.1");
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOCALPORT, 4912L);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE, 20L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, (long)1);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}

int BaseScraper::CurlWriter(char *pData, int pSize, int pNmemb, std::string *pBuffer)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (pBuffer != NULL) {
        pBuffer->append(pData, pSize * pNmemb);
        result = pSize * pNmemb;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note: I have simplified the code a little bit but my code works and the issue I am having is setting up IP/ports with the lines that are commented out.

Comment: Why are you getting disconnected? I don't understand why you think using same Port as TCPIP (which does not make sense) would affect anything. If you are getting disconnected it is because the server on the other end explicitly closed the connection. Do you know why (did you get an error message from them or an error code)?

Comment: This is not a C++ question (or any specific language) this is more about curl or maybe some IP protocol behavior.

Comment: I do not know the reason why it is getting disconnected, the application just stops receiving messages from the server and there is some logic in place so if no message is received for 5 seconds the connection gets closed and reopened (127.0.0.1:5009).... Just to provide more information I am multithreading while scraping, so I create around 200 instances of the scrapper class and access the website with different parameters in batches of 10. So when I look at a 'Net diagnostics' app I have, I see that many connections get created with IP 127.0.0.1 and different ports Ex:62522, 62587 etc.

Comment: Sounds like the server is detecting your scrapping (and you are not being very nice by creating 200 instances) and justifiably shutting you down or you are crashing the thread on the server that is sending data. I hope you are not being abusive to small sites and bringing down their servers.

Comment: Uhh, this is starting to look more like a conversation with so much back and forward.... But the server that is disconnecting is not the one I am scrapping, I am scrapping a website that is working fine, the server that is disconnecting I am only setting up a socket connection and listening at the messages they send. What I think is happening is that once one of the threads sets up a connection using same ip and port that the server I am listening at is using, then it breaks the established connection, that is why I want to define the port/IP for the 200 threads I use for scrapping.

Comment: @Larry A, the function curl_easy_cleanup - closes the created socket. You are the one who closes the socket and the connection to the remote server.